# What are the requirements from a collection in order for it to work with binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have this `Binding` (never-mind the fact that it's a `DataGridTextColumn` property):

```
...
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Whatever}"/>
...
```

And code-behind:

```
MyCollectionType<WhateverWrapper> { get; set; }
```

This is the `WhateverWrapper`:

```
class WhateverWrapper {
    public string Whatever { get; set; }
}
```

**My question is**: what are the requirements of the `MyCollectionType` in order for the `Binding` to work? What interfaces I must implement? or if it's not the interface inheritance that makes it work, then what is it? maybe specific method-names?

Comment: Do you want two way binding, or just one way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemsControl` control, which is base for controls like `ListBox`, `ListView`, `DataGrid`, `ComboBox` or `MenuItem`, has [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that is of `IEnumerable` type:

> public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }

and that's the main condition. You can bind to a collection if it implements `IEnumerable` interface.

> WPF never binds directly to a collection. If you specify a collection as a binding source, WPF actually binds to the collection's default view.

If you want your binding to auto pick up changes done to collection (add/remove items) then you'll need to implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface as well or use ready implementation like [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
You can read more about it under:

- [Using Collection Objects as a Binding
  Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#collections)
- [Binding to
  Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#binding_to_collections)